# Задача "Научная конференция"

Tags: c++

Имеется [задача](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1203)

> Работа научной конференции обычно разделена на несколько одновременно проходящих секций. Например, может быть секция параллельных вычислений, секция визуализации, секция сжатия данных и так далее.
>
> Очевидно, одновременная работа нескольких секций необходима, чтобы уменьшить время научной программы конференции и иметь больше времени на банкет, чаепитие и неофициальные обсуждения. Однако интересные доклады могут проходить одновременно в разных секциях.
>
> Участник записал расписание всех докладов, интересных ему. Он просит вас определить максимальное количество докладов, которые он сможет посетить.
>
> Исходные данные
>
> Первая строка содержит количество 1 ≤ N ≤ 100 000 интересных докладов. Каждая из следующих N строк содержит два целых числа Ts и Te, разделённых пробелом (1 ≤ Ts < Te ≤ 30 000). Эти числа — время начала и конца соответствующего доклада. Время задано в минутах от начала конференции.
>
> Результат
>
> Выведите максимальное количество докладов, которые участник может посетить. Участник не может посетить два доклада, идущих одновременно, и любые два доклада, которые он посещает, должны быть разделены хотя бы одной минутой. Например, если доклад кончается в 15, следующий доклад, который может быть посещён, должен начинаться в 16 или позже.

Программа получает memory limit На 5 тесте

```
     #include <stdio.h>  

     #include <vector>

     using namespace std;

    int N,tmp_begin, tmp_end,*dyn,maxv,Sum=0,error;
    vector<int> b, e,*vect;

    int search(int start){
        if(!dyn[start])
            return 0;
        maxv=vect[start][0];
        for(unsigned int i=1;i<vect[start].size();++i){
            if(dyn[maxv]<dyn[vect[start][i]])
                maxv=vect[start][i];
        }
        Sum++;
        search(maxv);
        return 0;
    }

int main() {
       scanf("%d",&N);
       dyn=new int[N];
       vect=new vector<int>[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;++i){
        scanf("%d%d",&tmp_begin,&tmp_end);
        b.push_back(tmp_begin);
        e.push_back(tmp_end);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<N;++i){
        for(int j=0;j<i;++j){
            if(e[i]+1<=b[j])
                vect[i].push_back(j);
        }
        for(int k=i+1;k<N;++k){
            if(e[i]+1<=b[k])
                vect[i].push_back(k);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<N;++i){
        dyn[i]=vect[i].size();
    }

    maxv=0;
    for(int i=1;i<N;++i){
        if(dyn[maxv]<dyn[i])
            maxv=i;
    }
    Sum++;
    error=search(maxv);

    if(!error){
        printf("%d",Sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Не прошу решить за меня, прошу подсказать оптимальное решение.

Comment: С изменением int на uShort добрался до 7 теста.

Comment: Переписал без рекурсии - не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решал так, создал массив из 30000 элементов. Индекс элемента соответствует времени конца доклада, а само значение это время начала доклада (соответственно, если значение 0, то ни один доклад в данный момент времени не заканчивается).
При считывании данных о каждом докладе, добавлял доклад, если до этого не было докладов заканчивающихся в это время, либо был который начинается раньше (он на нам не нужен, т.к. понятно из 2х заканчивающихся в одно время по крайней мере он будет не хуже).
Затем мы идем по всем элементам (то есть смотрим на каждый момент времени максимальное количество докладов) и если элемент равен 0, то количество докладов равно количеству докладов в предыдущий момент времени. Иначе смотрим 2 значения: количество докладов на предыдущем шаге и количество докладов за минуту до начала заканчивающегося в данный момент. Т.е. если у нас массив d и мы находимся на i-м элементе, то выбираем максимум из d[i-1] и d[d[i]-1]+1. Надеюсь вы поняли :) Ответ находится в d[30000]

Comment: Хорошее решение, я бы до него не додумался, а сам решал через графы.

Answer (score 0):

Для простоты введем структуру

```
struct doklad
{
    int a,b; //a - время начала доклада и b - время конца доклада
};
```

теперь отсортируем массив докладов, так что бы доклад у которого время окончания меньше был впереди, если есть два доклада у которых время окончания одинаково, то первее должен быть, тот у которого время начала больше.

После сортировки идем от 1го до последнего доклада. Допустим последний доклад на который мы пошли с номером i (m[i].a, m[i].b), а сейчас мы думаем можем ли мы пойти на доклад с номером j , (i меньше j, все доклады перебираем по очереди) . Если время конца i-го доклада меньше, чем время начала j-го доклада, то мы идем на доклад j. И так же рассматриваем пар дальше.

Это стандартное решение на жадность.

Итого: время работы O(N*logN), памяти O(N)

Comment: Эээ разе O(N*logN)???

Comment: тут время работы можно сказать что равно времени работы сортировки, если использовать логарифмическую сортировку, то как раз и будет O(N*logN)

Comment: А вы попробуйте сдать, почему-то я сомневаюсь в ваших пробегах (и думается на худших тестах даст O(N*N)). Либо мы тут идем один раз (т.е. если нашли j, то обратно не возвращаемся, проверить остальные пути), либо мы возвращаемся и перебираем остальные пути?

Вот например если такой тест:

5

1 10

2 11

11 20

12 21

21 30

22 32

33 34


Сразу написал в сортированном виде, как будет выглядеть порядок прохода?

Comment: возможно я неверно высказал свое решение. у меня Accepted.
Мы один раз проходим по отсортированному массиву, решая берем этот элемент или нет.
1) 1 10 - так как он первый.
2) 2 11 - брать не можем
3) 11 20 - берем 10<11
4) 12 21 - не берем
5) 21 30 - берем 20<21
6) 22 32 - не берем
7) 33 34 - берем 30<33
Ответ 4 доклада

Comment: ну да, я не совсем правильно понял. Спасибо